# Is auth customization secure in django?

Tags: python, django, security

I've extended user model with o2o relationship model (UserProfile). I want to make logging in with email/password instead of username/password. So I customized the auth backend.

Is logging in vulnerable with that way of authentication?

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.contrib.auth.backends import ModelBackend

class EmAuth(ModelBackend):
    def authenticate(self, request, username=None, password=None, **kwargs):
        UserModel = get_user_model()
        try:
            user = UserModel.objects.get(email=username)
        except UserModel.DoesNotExist:
            return None
        else:
            if user.check_password(password):
                return user
        return None

    def get_user(self, user_id):
        UserModel = get_user_model()
        try:
            return UserModel.objects.get(pk=user_id)
        except UserModel.DoesNotExist:
            return None
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't really change anything serious. The only difference on your code is that you get the user by email and the rest is pretty much the same. The `check_password` function you are using is a built-in function which is the same that the default authentication method uses. So in term of vulnerability in your code, you have nothing to worry about.